# Restrict IAM users to a single VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I have two VPC in my account. One for Test and other for Prod environment.

I am trying to setup IAM user accounts for developers, with permission boundaries, so that developers only has access to create/modify resources in Test VPC.

How do I do that? Can you share a sample policy JSON?

Comment: It is far better to set up separate test and prod accounts. You can use a condition on _some_ operations, but not all, and developers typically need wide-ranging permissions in the test account to identify problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "only has access to Test VPC"? Are you referring to the ability to create EC2 instances in a VPC, or are you referring to the ability to login/use resources in a VPC? Please edit your question to add more details rather than responding in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

An Amazon VPC is a virtual network.

It is not possible to **control access to a network based on "users"** because the network has no knowledge of users. It can only control traffic by IP address and protocol.

If you want developers to be able to login to instances in Test environment, but not a Prod environment, you would either need to **control access on the instances themselves** (eg when they login to an EC2 instance), or **control access to the network** (eg by controlling access to a VPN connection or having developers access resources on a network with a known IP address range).

This is exactly the same as controlling access on a corporate network — developers could be placed on a network that has access to Test resources, while Sys Admins could be placed on a network that has access to Prod resources. This has to do with how their computer is connected to the network, rather than "who" they are.

If, instead, your goal is to **restrict the Dev's ability to create/change resources in a VPC**, then this can be done by adding *conditions* a IAM policies. For example, granting them the ability to launch an EC2 instance but only in the Test VPC.

See: [How to Help Lock Down a User’s Amazon EC2 Capabilities to a Single VPC | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-help-lock-down-a-users-amazon-ec2-capabilities-to-a-single-vpc/)

Comment: My goal was to restrict the Dev's ability to create/change resources in a VPC. I was expecting a simple "permission boundary" policy that limits access to all resources(of all types) in a VPC, while providing access to another VPC, in the same account.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not that easy. You would need to add **Conditions** on any command that lets them create resources, so that those resources are limited to a specific VPC. There is no "permission boundary" for VPCs. See: [How to Help Lock Down a User’s Amazon EC2 Capabilities to a Single VPC | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-help-lock-down-a-users-amazon-ec2-capabilities-to-a-single-vpc/)

Comment: It is not just best practice, but highly encouraged to use different accounts for different environments. This will give you true separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

What I get is you are trying to restrict users to the services which are under a particular VPC. I did the same thing for allowing users to update Lambda functions which are inside a particular VPC only. This can be done like below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllResources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyLambdaUpdatIfNotInsideVPC",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "lambda:VpcIds": "your vpc id"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In this way you can restrict users from accessing the resources which are outside your VPC by writing services and their specific actions in the deny statement.